# Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table which have a column **order_date**  of date type.

query:

```
INSERT INTO uni_data_temp(sale_order_item_code, 
            order_date, sale_order_item_status, tracking_number, dispatch_date, 
            user_id) VALUES ('1000932515',  cast('16/05/2015' as date), 'DISPATCHED', 'UNIPAYP1958141', '2015/05/20', '4')
```

when I am running this query it gives error:

> ```
> ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "16/05/2015"
> SQL state: 22008
> Hint: Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
> Character: 380
> ```

then I changed the query

```
INSERT INTO uni_data_temp(sale_order_item_code, 
            order_date, sale_order_item_status, tracking_number, dispatch_date, 
            user_id) VALUES ('1000932515',  cast('2015/05/16' as date), 'DISPATCHED', 'UNIPAYP1958141', '2015/05/20', '4')
```

It works fine.

but my problem is my date may be in any style (yyyy/mm/dd or dd/mm/yyyy) how i can cast it according databse ?

Any kind of date format convert into system  database.

Thank You

Comment: You can use `SELECT TO_CHAR(NOW(), 'yyyy/mm/dd')::date;`

Comment: how i can apply this on my table i used '16/05/2015' instead of `now()` it still giving error:       function to_char(unknown, unknown) is not unique

Comment: If the date "may be in any style" you are out of luck. PG recognizes many date formats but some are ambiguous and some have a default interpretation (`mm/dd/yyyy` in your case). You should probably set some standard at the client side such that all dates are entered in a specific format and then you can use `to_date()` to make PG understand it in case it is not ISO style.

Comment: @Patrick it is bad news for me

Comment: If you get dates in different formats you should also get the format from there. I.e. some person or system giving you '01/02/2015' should also be able to tell you whether this is 'MM/DD/YYYY' or 'DD/MM/YYYY'. Otherwise it is impossible to guarantee importing the dates correctly. If you get the format, simply apply it: `to_date(:datestring, :formatstring)`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You are using strings for the dates and are relying on session settings to interprete the strings correctly. Use supported date literals instead so as to be independent from settings.

In PostgreSQL (and the SQL standard for that matter)  DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD' is considered a date literal and is the format I would recommend. So use

```
INSERT INTO uni_data_temp
  ( sale_order_item_code
  , order_date
  , sale_order_item_status
  , tracking_number
  , dispatch_date
  , user_id
  ) 
VALUES 
  ( '1000932515'
  , DATE '2015-05-16'
  , 'DISPATCHED'
  , 'UNIPAYP1958141'
  , DATE '2015-05-20'
  , 4
  );
```

(Thanks to a_horse_with_no_name for pointing me to the correct date literal syntax in PostgreSQL.)

If, however, you get the dates as strings from somewhere, you need to apply the according format:

```
TO_DATE('06/05/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY')
TO_DATE('05/06/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: When someone says "this costs 10", you will ask "10 what? Dollars? Cents? Euros?" The information 10 alone is incomplete. When someone says put the date '01/02/2015' in the database, you will ask "Is 01 the day and 02 the month or vice versa?" The information '01/02/2015' alone is incomplete. DD is for day, MM for month, YYYY for year. If the answer is "It is day-month-year", then the format is 'DD/MM/YYYY'. If your question gets no answer, you cannot put the data into your database; it is incomplete and you might mistakenly import wrong data; so refuse to do it.

Comment: My preferred way of writing date, time or timestamp literals is the ANSI syntax: `date '2016-01-13'` or `timestamp '2016-01-13 17:38:42'` which has the added benefit that it works across multiple (although not all) DBMS

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Thanks for he information. This is my preferred way, too. I know it to work in Oracle, but didn't know PostgreSQL uses the same syntax. I googled date literals in postgre and all I found was strings without the date or timestamp keyword. (Stupid me, it's so easy to find. It's in Date/Time Functions and Operators http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/functions-datetime.html). You are right, this should be done so. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: That's the way it's defined in the SQL Standard (btw: it's Postgres, not Postgre)

Answer (score 9):

In your postgresql.conf you have a setting called datestyle it is composed of two parts out and in.
Might be set as `iso, mdy` (output as ISO and input as american) try setting it as `iso, dmy`

[image: screenshot]